# Extraneous Ubuntu One icon on the Unity Launcher?

Tags: ubuntu-one, launcher

After installing Ubuntu One and starting a synchronization, I noticed that when I have the Ubuntu One dialog visible, I will have 2 icons for Ubuntu One on the Unity Launcher.  One appears to be the application that is uploading.  The other indicates "waiting to install" when I hover the cursor over it.

Why do I have another Ubuntu One icon that is waiting for installation when I have already installed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon might disappear if you reboot.